# Is there a way to modify CSS contents before browser loads it?

Tags: javascript, css, browser

I had an idea - use "css variables" inside media queries. It is not supported and maybe will be in future via env() function (current as draft - https://drafts.csswg.org/css-env-1/).

But what if I was able to modify CSS contents before it is parsed? I could just "replace" these css variables before browser would start parsing CSS as is.

Before parsing and replacing:
`@media (min-width:var(--size-lg))`

Could be after replacing and before parsing:
`@media (min-width:64rem)` or `@media (min-width:1024px)`

I can do this via .htaccess + php. But I am wondering if there is a way to modify CSS before browser does parsing? If yes, it seems to me, that this could be a better way.

Comment: Have you tried using CSS preprocessors like LESS or SASS?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Justinas the point is, that these values would be changed in final app based on user needs. If this would not be the need, we would stick with SASS/SCSS as usual. Plus I am curious if there is a way to be able to make changes before browser parse the CSS.

Comment: @Doctore Yes, your back-end can output CSS content with per-user changes injected. E.g. `.my-div {color: <?= $user->getPref('color'); ?>;}`

Comment: @Justinas yes, this is 1 option. But because there would be sources from other DEVs I can't change, I would like to come up with solution the the end.

I already created a prototype, where JS changes all style tags and replaces content. And all links are placed inline and content replaced.

But I would pretty much like to know if there is a way to achieve that in browser level / pre-parsing state.

Because then it would be universal solution.

Answer (score 0):

method for updating css by php..
create separate file
There are css frameworks like: Sass it can be used to modify the CSS code before it's compiled

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to pre-compile your CSS:

1. Use compilers like LESS or SASS that allows wider range of features than vanilla CSS.
2. Your back-end can output CSS file content.

E.g. using PHP:

```php
.my-class {
    color: <?= $user->getPref('css:color'); ?>;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.php">
```